# Consulta MySQL com Loop Infinito no C#

Tags: c#, mysql, for

Estou fazendo um projeto com criação de objetos dinâmicos com CSS, após ele entrar no for, ele insere todos os dados do banco de dados direitinho, porém aparentemente no final ele faz um loop infinito e aparece está mensagem:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Web.dll

```
            int qtd = 0;

            clsNoticia noticia = new clsNoticia();
            List<string> codigosNoticias = new List<string>();

                for (int i = 0; i < codigosNoticias.Count; i++)
                {
                    noticia.carregaNoticia(codigosNoticias[i]);

                    #region Noticias Criadas Dinamicamente
                    Label lblTituloNoticia = new Label();
                    lblTituloNoticia.CssClass = "tituloNoticia";
                    lblTituloNoticia.ID = "tituloNoticia_" + noticia.cd_noticia;
                    lblTituloNoticia.Text = noticia.nm_titulo;

                    Label lblLinhaFina = new Label();
                    lblLinhaFina.CssClass = "linhaFina";
                    lblLinhaFina.ID = "linhaFina_" + noticia.cd_noticia;
                    lblLinhaFina.Text = noticia.nm_linha_fina;

                    Panel pnlTituloNoticia = new Panel();
                    pnlTituloNoticia.ID = "pnlTituloNoticia";
                    pnlTituloNoticia.Controls.Add(lblTituloNoticia);

                    Panel pnlLinhaFina = new Panel();
                    pnlLinhaFina.ID = "pnlLinhaFina";
                    pnlLinhaFina.Controls.Add(lblLinhaFina);

                    Image img_noticia = new Image();
                    if (noticia.ic_destaque)
                    {
                        img_noticia.CssClass = "col1Img";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (qtd <= 2)
                        {
                            img_noticia.CssClass = "col2Img";
                            qtd++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            img_noticia.CssClass = "col3Img";
                            qtd++;

                            if (qtd == 6)
                            {
                                qtd = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (File.Exists(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + @"\images\noticias\" + noticia.cd_noticia + ".jpg"))
                    {
                        img_noticia.ImageUrl = "~/images/noticias/" + noticia.cd_noticia + ".jpg";
                    }

                    HyperLink lnkNoticia = new HyperLink();
                    lnkNoticia.ID = "link_" + noticia.cd_noticia;
                    lnkNoticia.CssClass = "linkPadrao";
                    lnkNoticia.Controls.Add(img_noticia);
                    lnkNoticia.Controls.Add(pnlTituloNoticia);
                    lnkNoticia.Controls.Add(pnlLinhaFina);

                    Panel pnlNoticia = new Panel();
                    pnlNoticia.ID = "noticia_" + noticia.cd_noticia;

                    if (noticia.ic_destaque)
                    {
                        pnlNoticia.CssClass = "col1";
                        pnlNoticia.CssClass = "mainContBloco";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (qtd <= 2)
                        {
                            pnlNoticia.CssClass = "col2";
                            pnlNoticia.CssClass = "col2Bloco";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pnlNoticia.CssClass = "col3";
                            pnlNoticia.CssClass = "col3Bloco";

                            if (qtd == 6)
                            {
                                qtd = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    pnlNoticia.Controls.Add(lnkNoticia);
                    #endregion

                    pnlNoticia.Controls.Add(pnlNoticia);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Era um erro sintático mesmo, na última linha de código coloquei `pnlNoticia.Controls.Add(pnlNoticia); ` porém havia criado um Panel com o mesmo nome no index.html, então apenas tive que mudar o nome, por isso não executava, mas obrigado pela ajuda :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na terceira linha você cria uma lista vazia `codigosNoticias`ou seja `codigosNoticias.Count == 0`

Então na quarta linha você usa `codigosNoticias.Count` para comparar com `i` o que faz com que o código dentro do `for` nunca seja executado.

```
// Esse for quivale a for (int i = 0; i < 0; i++)
for (int i = 0; i < codigosNoticias.Count; i++)
{
  //Esse bloco nunca é executado
}
```

O que falta nesse código é preencher a lista `codigosNoticias` antes de tentar processa-lá.

Answer (score 1):

Precisaria de mais informações das classes envolvidas, normalmente este tipo de erro acontece por referencia circular entre instância de classe: class1 depende de classe 2, que depende de class1.